# Frame inside A OOP Tkinter Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Right so I am trying to put a frame into the waiter page to split it into different frames
like this design but nothings working.

This is the design:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to create a basic `Frame` inside but it doesn't appear.
The `Frame` that I created doesnt throw an error however it might be in a different position, So I attempted to move it but it didn't change anything and just didn't display it on the `WaiterPage`.

**Note** There is no validation for the login so just click login after choosing `WaiterPage`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import SUNKEN, Label, ttk
from tkinter import IntVar
from tkinter.constants import BOTH, BOTTOM, CENTER, GROOVE, LEFT, RIGHT
from typing import Container

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        self.bg = tk.PhotoImage(file="D:/talha\Documents\Projects For Portfolio\Some Fun\CourseWork\Testbg.png")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.geometry("800x500")
        self.resizable(False,False)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for page in (ManagerPage, WaiterPage, Login):
            frame = page(container,self)
            self.frames[page] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(page)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class WaiterPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        MainFrame = tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        RightFrame = tk.Frame(MainFrame, background='blue')


class ManagerPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="Manager Page:").pack()

        LeftFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        LeftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

        CurrentTables = tk.Listbox(LeftFrame, width=70,height=33).pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)

        AddTable = ttk.Button(self, text="Add Table").place(width=160,height=37,relx=0.65, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        AddBooking = ttk.Button(self, text="Add Booking").place(width=160,height=37,relx=0.875, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        ViewBooking = ttk.Button(self, text="View Booking").place(width=160, height=37,relx=0.65, rely=0.65, anchor=CENTER)
        Collection = ttk.Button(self, text="Collection").place(width=160,height=37,relx=0.875, rely=0.65, anchor=CENTER)
        Inventory = ttk.Button(self, text="View Inventory").place(width=160,height=37,relx=0.75, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)
        Exit = ttk.Button(self, text="Exit").place(width=160,height=37,relx=0.75, rely=0.9, anchor=CENTER)


class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        def CallBack():
            if ManagerValue.get() == 1:
                WaiterCheck.configure(state='disabled')

            if WaiterValue.get() == 1:
                ManagerCheck.configure(state='disabled')

            if ManagerValue.get() == 0:
                WaiterCheck.configure(state='normal')

            if WaiterValue.get() == 0:
                ManagerCheck.configure(state='normal')

        def CheckPage():
            if ManagerValue.get() == 1:
                self.controller.show_frame(ManagerPage)
            if WaiterValue.get() == 1:
                self.controller.show_frame(WaiterPage)

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label_bkgr = tk.Label(self, image=self.controller.bg)
        label_bkgr.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

        tk.Label(self, text="Username: ",font=("Segoe UI", 12),bg='#59C8E3').place(relx=0.3, rely=0.35, anchor=CENTER)
        tk.Label(self, text="Password: ",font=("Segoe UI", 12),bg='#59C8E3').place(relx=0.3, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)

        ManagerValue = IntVar()
        WaiterValue = IntVar()

        ManagerCheck = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Manager",variable=ManagerValue,command=CallBack,font=("Segoe UI", 12),bg='#59C8E3',activebackground='#59C8E3')
        ManagerCheck.place(relx=0.43, rely=0.535, anchor=CENTER)
        WaiterCheck = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Waiter",variable=WaiterValue,command=CallBack,font=("Segoe UI", 12),bg='#59C8E3',activebackground='#59C8E3')
        WaiterCheck.place(relx=0.59, rely=0.535, anchor=CENTER)

        UserEntry = ttk.Entry(self)
        UserEntry.place(width=160,
        height=37,relx=0.5, rely=0.35, anchor=CENTER)

        PassEntry = ttk.Entry(self)
        PassEntry.configure(show="*")
        PassEntry.place(width=160,
        height=37,relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)

        Submit = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit",command=CheckPage)
        Submit.place(width=160,
        height=37,relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you posted a link to a file on your computer, which we can't see.

Comment: Oh okay give me a sec ill try to fix it

Comment: Also, if login isn't strictly required to reproduce the problem, please remove that functionality from the code. Also, please remove external files that aren't required to reproduce the problem, such as `DatabaseManagement`.

Comment: I do need the login so you can choose to go to the waiter page

Comment: _you_ might need the login, but _we_ don't. The code should be the fewest lines of code possible to reproduce the problem and the login screen is not part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you never call `pack` or `grid` on `RightFrame`, so it will never appear.

The second problem is that `RightFrame` needs to be a child of `self` because `MainFrame` is `None`.

```
class WaiterPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        RightFrame = tk.Frame(self, background='blue')
        RightFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

I don't know if `pack(fill="both", expand=True)` are the right options, but the point is you have to call `pack` or `grid` or `place` on the frame in order for it to be visible.